# Background Image not fully displayed

Tags: css, jsp

I am trying to display a background image for a button. The button is saved as .png and used in JSP page. The problem is that, when button gets displayed, it only displays one half of the image, i want the whole image to be displayed.

CSS -

```
#btn {
background: url(../images/btn-blk.png) no-repeat;   
width: 100%;
}
```

JSP -

```
<input type="submit" value="Add" id="btn" />
```

What could the problem be? How to make the image display the whole width instead of left half alone?

-Thx in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the size of `btn` to be the size of your image in pixels. CSS has no idea how big your image is.

Because `BTN` is an inline element, `width:100%` refers to the width of the button, not your background image.

You need something like:

```
btn {
background: url(../images/btn-blk.png) no-repeat;   
width: 50px;
height:20px;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried adding the width in pixels and you wr right, i get the image completely. But it is too big for the page, could you please also tell me how to reduce the size of this image? - Thx

Answer (score 1):

1. Are you sure that you posted corect css code? It should be "#btn" not "btn".
2. Since you know your width of btn-blk.png, why don't you put it in css, instead using width:100%? Attach here the image btn-blk and maybe we will be able to understand better what you want to do.

Comment: You Where right. # is there in my code. Have changed this in my question. -Thx

Answer (score 0):

Check with a DOM examiner (FireBug, Chrome's internal one, or something like that) and see that your `<input>` tag really is big enough.

As a FYI: the "width: 100%" does not apply to the background image size, but to the element's size, relative to its parent.

Comment: Hi, I do have the space, the width had to be mentioned in pixels... That was the problem - Thx

Answer (score 0):

There are other ways of putting an image in a form that may be more appropriate:

1. `<input type="image" src="../images/btn-blk.png">`
2. `<button><img src="../images/btn-blk.png"></button>`